# Let not A nor B or Let neither A nor B?

Tags: neither-nor

I am wondering if this is correct, I know there is a "neither A nor B" rule but it sounds unnatural.  This is to be engraved on a head stone, the tone is solemn rather than informal.  Any help/suggesitons would be great.

"Let not our laughter nor our stride falter for we draw strength from your strength, we draw joy from your vibrancy; we carry on through your love."

Comment: not... nor... strikes me as a double negative that can be fixed with making the nor an or. Could also strike the second our.  "let not our laughter or stride falter"

Comment: Your quote doesn't match your question. "Let not our laughter nor our stride falter" is perfectly fine, if a bit archaic. "Let nor our laughter..." would be totally wrong.

Comment: ...but as @stephanie says I'm probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Some languages (not English) do use the "nor A nor B" type of construction.  I guess user126724 speaks one of those languages.

Comment: They're both archaic and ponderous. 19th-century bloviation.

Comment: @JohnLawler so are headstones. Arguably.

Answer (score 5):

"Let not our laughter nor our stride falter..." is correct English, and it sounds impressive as well.

The use of "nor" is to replace an "or" in a negative sense.  The first "not" makes this phrase negative, and so "nor" is proper here.

Comment: I would add that "not" has the function of negating "let" rather than "our laughter"; in more colloquial English, it would be "do not let our laughter (n)or our stride falter..."

Answer (score 1):

It's `let neither A nor B`. It can't be `let nor A nor B` because the first nor is comparing one thing to nothing, which goes against the function of the or/nor operand of language.

See: [How to use Either, Neither, Or, and Nor Correctly](http://thewritepractice.com/how-to-use-either-neither-or-and-nor-correctly/)

Comment: I think the title text is wrong... In the body of the question, the OP says "Let **NOT** our"... not "let nor".

Comment: I think it may have gotten edited, but I'm going to leave it since there's already a correct answer.

Comment: If it got edited, there's no history of it.

Comment: @Catija There isn't edit history if the OP makes an edit shortly after the post, I believe.